# What are the RPC endpoints that is usually unique to Substrate vs the unique to Polkadot nodes?

Tags: polkadot, rpc, substrate-node, typegen

I used typegen to generate types for Substrate, Kusama and Polkadot networks. And I got the exact same types for the **rpc** endpoints (rpc methods). Is this normal? Should not be there some unique endpoints to the relay chain vs the execution node?

Answer (score 0):

By default the ports are same, as Substrate, Kusama and Polkadot networks are not meant to be run on the same system, so there is nothing wrong to have the same endpoints.

Comment: Having the same default ports is irrelevant to the question. The question is about the rpc endpoints and not the url:port.  However, I edited the question to emphasize more on this. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, The edgeware.json file does not contain the list of RPC methods for the node. And the typegen does not depend on it to generate the `augment-api-rpc.ts` file which contains the list of rpc methods organized inside namespaces.

However, someone can query the connected node to check for the supported methods by calling the `rpc_methods` endpoint on the node.